# Jersey - return list of XmlRootElement/Entities - MessageBodyWriter not found

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

There are a million of these JAX-RS serialization snowflakes. Let me add one more.

I have a JPA/JAXb annotated class:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo implements Serializable {
//..
}
```

I have a service that seeks to return a list of these objects as JSON:

```
@Path("foo")
public class FooService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response listFoos() {
        // get hibernate session
        List<Foo> foos = session.createQuery("from Foo").list();
        GenericEntity<List<Foo>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Foo>>(foos) {};
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }
}
```

I have tried a number of variations. The one that looks the best, to me is like

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Foo> listFoos() {
        // get session ..
        return session.createQuery("from Foo").list();
    }
```

All give me some slight variation of:

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for
media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, 
genericType=java.util.List<com.bar.baz.Foo>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add a dependency like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Technically, serializing your lists is considered bad practice.  Many people recommend using a wrapper object to encapsulate them for you.

Comment: thanks @JohnAment, do you have any more details about how to craft such a wrapper object and what its purpose is?